# How to import ReductionV2 in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, import, reduction

I want to import the method ReductionV2 in tensorflow but I cannot find the source. I'm looking for this method:

`losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO`

But when I try to import it I get:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.utils.losses_utils'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.keras.losses.Reduction`, default value will be AUTO